# Windows Phone 7 Stock Pivot Control Slow?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I have a stock unedited version of Mango's Pivot Application and when I goto run it the control it really slow, is there a way to speed this up?

By slow I mean, when I am running my finger across the screen multiple times fast - as I would do on the iPhone it's really slow I take my finger off and it's still going through the windows.

I am also testing this on a real device (HTC HD7) on other apps such as IM+, Kik Messenger, etc... it works fine.

Code for XAML:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="PivotApp1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768" 
d:DataContext="{d:DesignData SampleData/MainViewModelSampleData.xaml}"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait"  Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <!--Pivot Control-->
    <controls:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION">
        <!--Pivot item one-->
        <controls:PivotItem Header="first">
            <!--Double line list with text wrapping-->
            <ListBox x:Name="FirstListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                      <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Height="78">
                          <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                          <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                      </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </controls:PivotItem>

        <!--Pivot item two-->
        <controls:PivotItem Header="second"> 
            <!--Triple line list no text wrapping-->
                <ListBox x:Name="SecondListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="12,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineThree}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="12,-6,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
        </controls:PivotItem>
    </controls:Pivot>
</Grid>

<!--Sample code showing usage of ApplicationBar-->
<!--<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>-->
```

C# MainPage.xaml.cs Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

namespace PivotApp1
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Set the data context of the listbox control to the sample data
            DataContext = App.ViewModel;
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
        }

        // Load data for the ViewModel Items
        private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
            {
                App.ViewModel.LoadData();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

C# App.xaml.cs Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;

namespace PivotApp1
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        private static MainViewModel viewModel = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// A static ViewModel used by the views to bind against.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The MainViewModel object.</returns>
        public static MainViewModel ViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                // Delay creation of the view model until necessary
                if (viewModel == null)
                    viewModel = new MainViewModel();

                return viewModel;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Provides easy access to the root frame of the Phone Application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The root frame of the Phone Application.</returns>
        public PhoneApplicationFrame RootFrame { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor for the Application object.
        /// </summary>
        public App()
        {
            // Global handler for uncaught exceptions. 
            UnhandledException += Application_UnhandledException;

            // Standard Silverlight initialization
            InitializeComponent();

            // Phone-specific initialization
            InitializePhoneApplication();

            // Show graphics profiling information while debugging.
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                // Display the current frame rate counters
                Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;

                // Show the areas of the app that are being redrawn in each frame.
                //Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableRedrawRegions = true;

                // Enable non-production analysis visualization mode, 
                // which shows areas of a page that are handed off to GPU with a colored overlay.
                //Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableCacheVisualization = true;

                // Disable the application idle detection by setting the UserIdleDetectionMode property of the
                // application's PhoneApplicationService object to Disabled.
                // Caution:- Use this under debug mode only. Application that disables user idle detection will continue to run
                // and consume battery power when the user is not using the phone.
                PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
            }
        }

        // Code to execute when the application is launching (eg, from Start)
        // This code will not execute when the application is reactivated
        private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        // Code to execute when the application is activated (brought to foreground)
        // This code will not execute when the application is first launched
        private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Ensure that application state is restored appropriately
            if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
            {
                App.ViewModel.LoadData();
            }
        }

        // Code to execute when the application is deactivated (sent to background)
        // This code will not execute when the application is closing
        private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        // Code to execute when the application is closing (eg, user hit Back)
        // This code will not execute when the application is deactivated
        private void Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            // Ensure that required application state is persisted here.
        }

        // Code to execute if a navigation fails
        private void RootFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                // A navigation has failed; break into the debugger
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            }
        }

        // Code to execute on Unhandled Exceptions
        private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            }
        }

        #region Phone application initialization

        // Avoid double-initialization
        private bool phoneApplicationInitialized = false;

        // Do not add any additional code to this method
        private void InitializePhoneApplication()
        {
            if (phoneApplicationInitialized)
                return;

            // Create the frame but don't set it as RootVisual yet; this allows the splash
            // screen to remain active until the application is ready to render.
            RootFrame = new PhoneApplicationFrame();
            RootFrame.Navigated += CompleteInitializePhoneApplication;

            // Handle navigation failures
            RootFrame.NavigationFailed += RootFrame_NavigationFailed;

            // Ensure we don't initialize again
            phoneApplicationInitialized = true;
        }

        // Do not add any additional code to this method
        private void CompleteInitializePhoneApplication(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            // Set the root visual to allow the application to render
            if (RootVisual != RootFrame)
                RootVisual = RootFrame;

            // Remove this handler since it is no longer needed
            RootFrame.Navigated -= CompleteInitializePhoneApplication;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

C# MainViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;


namespace PivotApp1
{
    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            this.Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// A collection for ItemViewModel objects.
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; private set; }

        private string _sampleProperty = "Sample Runtime Property Value";
        /// <summary>
        /// Sample ViewModel property; this property is used in the view to display its value using a Binding
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string SampleProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return _sampleProperty;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != _sampleProperty)
                {
                    _sampleProperty = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("SampleProperty");
                }
            }
        }

        public bool IsDataLoaded
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates and adds a few ItemViewModel objects into the Items collection.
        /// </summary>
        public void LoadData()
        {
            // Sample data; replace with real data
            this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "runtime one", LineTwo = "Maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum", LineThree = "Facilisi faucibus habitant inceptos interdum lobortis nascetur pharetra placerat pulvinar sagittis senectus sociosqu" });
            this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "runtime two", LineTwo = "Dictumst eleifend facilisi faucibus", LineThree = "Suscipit torquent ultrices vehicula volutpat maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum dictumst eleifend facilisi faucibus" });
            this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "runtime three", LineTwo = "Habitant inceptos interdum lobortis", LineThree = "Habitant inceptos interdum lobortis nascetur pharetra placerat pulvinar sagittis senectus sociosqu suscipit torquent" });
            this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "runtime four", LineTwo = "Nascetur pharetra placerat pulvinar", LineThree = "Ultrices vehicula volutpat maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum dictumst eleifend facilisi faucibus habitant inceptos" });
            this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "runtime five", LineTwo = "Maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum", LineThree = "Maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum dictumst eleifend facilisi faucibus habitant inceptos interdum lobortis nascetur" });
            this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "runtime six", LineTwo = "Dictumst eleifend facilisi faucibus", LineThree = "Pharetra placerat pulvinar sagittis senectus sociosqu suscipit torquent ultrices vehicula volutpat maecenas praesent" });
            this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "runtime seven", LineTwo = "Habitant inceptos interdum lobortis", LineThree = "Accumsan bibendum dictumst eleifend facilisi faucibus habitant inceptos interdum lobortis nascetur pharetra placerat" });
            this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "runtime eight", LineTwo = "Nascetur pharetra placerat pulvinar", LineThree = "Pulvinar sagittis senectus sociosqu suscipit torquent ultrices vehicula volutpat maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum" });
            this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "runtime nine", LineTwo = "Maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum", LineThree = "Facilisi faucibus habitant inceptos interdum lobortis nascetur pharetra placerat pulvinar sagittis senectus sociosqu" });
            this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "runtime ten", LineTwo = "Dictumst eleifend facilisi faucibus", LineThree = "Suscipit torquent ultrices vehicula volutpat maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum dictumst eleifend facilisi faucibus" });
            this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "runtime eleven", LineTwo = "Habitant inceptos interdum lobortis", LineThree = "Habitant inceptos interdum lobortis nascetur pharetra placerat pulvinar sagittis senectus sociosqu suscipit torquent" });
            this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "runtime twelve", LineTwo = "Nascetur pharetra placerat pulvinar", LineThree = "Ultrices vehicula volutpat maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum dictumst eleifend facilisi faucibus habitant inceptos" });
            this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "runtime thirteen", LineTwo = "Maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum", LineThree = "Maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum dictumst eleifend facilisi faucibus habitant inceptos interdum lobortis nascetur" });
            this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "runtime fourteen", LineTwo = "Dictumst eleifend facilisi faucibus", LineThree = "Pharetra placerat pulvinar sagittis senectus sociosqu suscipit torquent ultrices vehicula volutpat maecenas praesent" });
            this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "runtime fifteen", LineTwo = "Habitant inceptos interdum lobortis", LineThree = "Accumsan bibendum dictumst eleifend facilisi faucibus habitant inceptos interdum lobortis nascetur pharetra placerat" });
            this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "runtime sixteen", LineTwo = "Nascetur pharetra placerat pulvinar", LineThree = "Pulvinar sagittis senectus sociosqu suscipit torquent ultrices vehicula volutpat maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum" });

            this.IsDataLoaded = true;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (null != handler)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

C# ItemViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace PivotApp1
{
    public class ItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _lineOne;
        /// <summary>
        /// Sample ViewModel property; this property is used in the view to display its value using a Binding.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string LineOne
        {
            get
            {
                return _lineOne;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != _lineOne)
                {
                    _lineOne = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("LineOne");
                }
            }
        }

        private string _lineTwo;
        /// <summary>
        /// Sample ViewModel property; this property is used in the view to display its value using a Binding.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string LineTwo
        {
            get
            {
                return _lineTwo;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != _lineTwo)
                {
                    _lineTwo = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("LineTwo");
                }
            }
        }

        private string _lineThree;
        /// <summary>
        /// Sample ViewModel property; this property is used in the view to display its value using a Binding.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string LineThree
        {
            get
            {
                return _lineThree;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != _lineThree)
                {
                    _lineThree = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("LineThree");
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (null != handler)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm running the version of WP 7.1 which was released a few days ago on Microsoft's website.

I can't figure out how to get the application to speed up as it lags in comparison to iOS when bringing my finger across and it's not smooth, I take it off for a few seconds and it's still trying to catch up to where I was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you are using the stock Pivot application template as part of the windows phone SDK 7.1 (Mango RTM release), in which case there should be no issues.

I've just fired up the template locally and ran it with no issues, so you might want to try a fresh copy if you can.

In the template there is no C# to speak of, it just loads up two lists for displaying to the two list boxes in the view, nothing special there.  Granted it is not the most efficient way of doing this as the display will not render until BOTH the lists are populated, better to use some level of virtualisation and load the two lists separately for each view.

I take on board Claus's comment about using a grid over a stackpanel but in most cases unless you are using stack panels within stack panels there is no real issue and the benefit of how a stack panel handles layout can be a huge benefit.

let me know if you have done anything else to the default template and I'll expand where I can

Comment: Hi, this is a standard new project, no changes as of yet. The XAML was created by Microsoft as I haven't changed it, above I will add the C# code to both App.xaml.cs and MainPage.xaml.cs. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't related to your XAML. It's related to the C# code running in the background.

The problem is you're adding a heavy load to the UI thread, and as such the navigation between pivots, which is also running on the UI thread, lags heavily.

We'll need to see the related C# code (code-behind / viewmodel, etc.) to give more detailed advice.

As for your XAML, a good advice would be to use a `Grid` instead of `StackPanel` in your `DataTemplate` if possible, since it improves virtualization of the list elements.

Comment: Hi, this is a standard new project, no changes as of yet. The XAML was created by Microsoft as I haven't changed it, above I will add the C# code to both App.xaml.cs and MainPage.xaml.cs. Thank you.